# MATLAB Invalid MEX-file error/missing symbol invalid_argument/Missing symbol 'mexCallMATLAB' required by

Tags: linux, macos, matlab, mex, diplib

Here is the thing: I am trying to use Dipimage Tool.

1. The error info:

   > Finally: this is the error message generated by the low-level
   >   initialisation function:
   >   Invalid MEX-file '/home/myname/dip/common/mlv7_6/diplib/private/dip__initialise.mexa64': 
   >   Missing symbol '**mexCallMATLAB**' required by '/home/myname/dip/common/mlv7_6/diplib/private/dip__initialise.mexa64'
   >   Missing symbol '**mexErrMsgTxt**' required by '/home/myname/dip/common/mlv7_6/diplib/private/dip__initialise.mexa64'
   >   Missing symbol '**mexIsLocked**' required by '/home/myname/dip/common/mlv7_6/diplib/private/dip__initialise.mexa64'
   >   Missing symbol 'mexLock' required by '/home/myname/dip/common/mlv7_6/diplib/private/dip__initialise.mexa64'
   >   Missing symbol 'mexUnlock' required by '/home/myname/dip/common/mlv7_6/diplib/private/dip__initialise.mexa64'
   >   Missing symbol 'mxGetScalar' required by '/home/myname/dip/common/mlv7_6/diplib/private/dip__initialise.mexa64'
   >   Missing symbol 'mxGetString' required by '/home/myname/dip/common/mlv7_6/diplib/private/dip__initialise.mexa64'
   >   Missing symbol 'mexCallMATLAB' required by '/home/myname/dip/Linuxa64/lib/libdml_mlv7_6.so->/home/myname/dip/common/mlv7_6/diplib/private/dip__initialise.mexa64'
   >   .........
2. The related environment:

   > OS:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
   >   MATLAB: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/matlab
3. The things I have tried

3.1 Basic installation steps:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myname/dip/Linuxa64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>    (then in matlab)
>    addpath('/home/myname/software/dip/common/dipimage')
>    dip_initialise
>    (After this I got the bug)

3.2 I suspect about the LD_LIBARAY_PATH so

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

3.3 I tried the LD_PRELOAD

> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/libmex.so:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 \

I think the weirdest part is that the symbol I miss is from MATLAB? 
Now I am totally confused. So here I am. Please help~~~

Comment: Can you add the part of your code that causes this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This error happened when I was trying to use the [DIPimage tool](http://www.diplib.org/). But I think The error is not coursed by the code of DIPimage. The code I write is  `addpath('/home/myname/dip/common/dipimage')`
`dip_initialise`

Comment: What version of DIPimage are you using? Note that the paths you typed don't match (/home/myname/dip vs /home/myname/software/dip).